# How to use recursion to mix 2 strings and return both as 1 'interlaced' string?

Tags: string, python-3.x, recursion

I have written this program:

```
def mix(a,b):

    if len(a) != len(b):
        return
    else:
        return a[0]+b[0]+a[1]+b[1]+a[2]+b[2]+a[3]+b[3]
```

What this does, is take's 2 strings and 'interlaces' them together. So for example, if I chose `taco` as string 1 and `bowl` as string 2, it would return `tbaocwol`. If the strings' lengths differ, we will just return.

The problem I am coming across is the recursion in my else return statement. How can I write it so it would accept any length of strings and not be limited to 2, 3, or 4 letters? I hardcoded the indexes in my original code to see the result as I go along but I am stooped with this.

I do not want to use any loops or any string processing functions. 
Only ones I am open to using are slicing and/or global variables.
I also do not want to use `.remove()`, `index` or `.replace()`.

Note: I have seen a similar question but it was in java and I could not figure out the equivalencies to python.

Comment: Your function returns either `None` or a string, is that really the intended behavior?

Comment: @asimes Well, ideally, I don't really want it to do anything if the lengths are different. Maybe I can add in there a string `Error: both words should be same length.`. But pretty much, that is the intended behavior for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass on a sliced version of your string.

```
def mix(a,b):
    if len(a) != len(b):
        return
    elif not a:
        return ""
    else:
        return a[0] + b[0] + mix(a[1:], b[1:])
```

Some test cases:

```
>>> print(mix("Hello", "abcde"))
Haeblcldoe
>>> print(mix("Guten Tag", "ihgfedcba"))
Giuhtgefne dTcabga
>>> print(mix("Ni Hao", "Hello "))
NHie lHlaoo
```

Comment: You can shorten `len(a) == 0:
        return b
    elif len(b) == 0:
        return a` to `not a: return ''`.

Comment: @AlexHall, that's also a better replacement because the simpler the code, the better! Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

```
def mix(a,b):
    if len(a) != len(b):
        return ''
    if len(a) == 0:
        return ''
    else:
        return mix(a[:-1], b[:-1])+a[-1]+b[-1]
```

This should do the trick!

Comment: Semicolons are not necessary at the end of Python statements.